# Ajax.BeginForm using different submit buttons and different submit ways

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use different submit way by different submit button in Ajax.BeginForm ?

for example

```
MyView.cshtml :

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "result"
}, null))
{
    ....
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-default" name="Create" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-default" name="F1" value="F1" />
    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-default" name="F2" value="F2" />   
 }

    MyController :

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model, string F1, string F2)
    {
        if (F1 != null)
        {
            var model_new = myService.ReloadModel1();
            return View(model_new);
        }
        else if (F2 != null)
        {
            var model_new = myService.ReloadModel2();
            return View(model_new);
        }           

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            bool result = myService.Create(model);

            if (!result)
            {
                return Content("Failed");          
            }
            return Content("Success");          
        }         
    }
```

I want to reload the view model with a specific dropdownlist to the page when pass F1/F2 (normal post) and pass Create button (ajax post) to return the text result to the page to prevent page reload.

Is it possible to disable ajax post when using F1 and F2 button?

Comment: Just use the `$.ajax()` methods, which give you far more flexibility (and `Ajax.BeginForm()` is no longer supported an has even been dropped from the latest version of mvc)